# component vs directive event priority

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular2-directives

I have written a directive which accepts only numbers implementing `ControlValueAccessor`.

`onBlur` of that particular element I would update its model like below.

```
@HostListener('blur',['$event']) onBlur(event) {
    this.directiveModel = this.getOnlyNumberLogic();
    this.propagateChange(this.directiveModel); <-- update model
    this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'value', this.directiveModel);
  }
```

The above logic works perfectly, but the problem comes when I add `(blur)` on the component element's HTML like below:

```
<input type="text" name="number"
    #numberId="ngModel"
    required
    [(ngModel)]="obj.number"
    pattern="^\d{11}(?:\d{5})?$"
    numberOnly   <---- Directive
    (blur)="numberId.valid && onNumberBlur(numberId.value)"
    maxlength="16"/>
```

Every single time the component's `(blur)` executes first and then directive's `@HostListener('blur')`, because of which the `[(ngModel)]` isn't updating as the `this.propagateChange()` is inside the directive's `blur` is called later.

**Question:**

Is there anyway to set a priority that directive's blur should execute first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the above problem with `EventEmitter`. I have one `EventEmitter` for the directive :

`@Output() onDirectiveBlur = new EventEmitter();`

Then on directive's blur I would emit this event,

```
@HostListener('blur',['$event']) onBlur(event) {
  this.directiveModel = this.getOnlyNumberLogic();
  this.propagateChange(this.directiveModel); <-- update model
  this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'value', this.directiveModel);
  this.onDirectiveBlur.emit();
}
```

which is bind with the element in the component's HTML, like below:

```
 <input type="text" name="number"
    #numberId="ngModel"
    required
    [(ngModel)]="obj.number"
    pattern="^\d{11}(?:\d{5})?$"
    numberOnly   <---- Directive
    (onDirectiveBlur)="numberId.valid && onNumberBlur(numberId.value)"
    maxlength="16"/>
```

with this case the component's (custom) `blur` will only call after directive's `blur` and guarantees the model will always be updated.

I'm not accepting this as answer (for now) because I feel there would be some  better way than including event `onDirectiveBlur`, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Just a note please don't use `new EventEmitter<any>();` use `new EventEmitter();` the latter is more type safe and also easier to read. A lot of the time people fall into the trap of thinking that because `--noImplicitAny` is good that explicit `any`s are okay. They are a last resort. Please don't get into the habit of littering your code with them as it will make life miserable for you and others

Comment: Sorry, I get a bit heated about that topic ;)